# GPUImage2 return false when using image from screenshot iPhone X

Tags: iphone, swift, screenshot, gpuimage, iphone-x

I have tried to capturing screen of iPhone X and using GPUImage 2 for it.

```
let success = sharedImageProcessingContext.context.renderbufferStorage(Int(GL_RENDERBUFFER), from:self.layer as! CAEAGLLayer)
if !success {
    return
}
```

This code will be returned false and my app is crashed.

I have tried to using iPhone X's screenshot to send this image to other iOS devices and using other iOS devices' screenshot and this code still works.

Why? Can someone explain that?

Comment: I don't use GPUImage2, but when I look at your code I see that you are doing maybe *four* (or more) things on a single line. Have you attempted to break that line down to *individual* things that could cause `success` to be false?

Comment: I have tried this, but it still returns false...

Comment: On which specific thing? How could anyone here reproduce the issue you are having?

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with the same line of code and it seems my fix [helped someone else on a crash issue on iPhoneX](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage2/issues/226#issuecomment-366167899)

as a monkeypatch I changed the following lines (starts at line 62) in the RenderView.swift file:

```
sharedImageProcessingContext.context.renderbufferStorage(Int(GL_RENDERBUFFER), from:self.layer as! CAEAGLLayer)

var backingWidth:GLint = 0
var backingHeight:GLint = 0
glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GLenum(GL_RENDERBUFFER), GLenum(GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH), &backingWidth)
glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GLenum(GL_RENDERBUFFER), GLenum(GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT), &backingHeight)
```

by this:

```
let group = DispatchGroup()
group.enter()

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    sharedImageProcessingContext.context.renderbufferStorage(Int(GL_RENDERBUFFER), from:self.layer as! CAEAGLLayer)
    group.leave()
}
group.wait()

var backingWidth:GLint = 0
var backingHeight:GLint = 0
glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GLenum(GL_RENDERBUFFER), GLenum(GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH), &backingWidth)
glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GLenum(GL_RENDERBUFFER), GLenum(GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT), &backingHeight)
```

I'm guessing the initial issue you had was that this call:

```
sharedImageProcessingContext.context.renderbufferStorage(Int(GL_RENDERBUFFER), from:self.layer as! CAEAGLLayer)
```

needed to be done on the main thread (maybe iphoneX has more restrictive runtime when it comes to background threads modifying the UI). simply calling it on the main thread isn't enough though since over values need to be up to date too (which is why I wait until it is over to continue).
The duration of the pause is really short and negligible in my opinion.

EDIT: For future help it would be nice to tell us which file your line of code comes from. Some error logs would have helped too.

Comment: I just don't understand why do you put this code to DispatchGroup